# Asp.Net Web API action string route mapping

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a contoller named customer and an action method for GetAllCustomers which recieves single string input parameter as FirstName. The issue is that I want the url to be like

```
MyAPI/Customer/MyFirstName
```

but the above stated URL is not working for me instead it working as below

```
MyAPI/Customer?firstname=MyFirstName
```

How can I make it work like the first url using ApplicationRouting (nuget package)? I have configured the attrbute route for the action method as below.

```
[GET("Customer/{firstname}")]
public List<Customer> GetAllCustomersFirstname(String firstname)
{
//code goes here
}
```

**Edit**
 Here is the reference whatI am trying to achieve but it is not happening for me in ApiController

[Attribute Routing Github](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/wiki/Optional-Route-Parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Open up ApiConfig in the AppStart folder. You need to add the route for that particular action. I think you'll need more than just what you showed there for route since you have to tell it which action to call and what methods to allow. E.g.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "yourRoute",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{firstname}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "GetAllCustomersFirstname" });
```

Comment: I am using attribute routing I dont think that it is needed to add apiconfig entry or am I wrong ?

Comment: Your tag says MVC4, are you using a 3rd party package for attribute routing?

Comment: I am using AttributeRouting nuget

Comment: Ah. Would have been good to know that. I don't have any experience with that and I prefer not to set routes like that. I don't like having extra code in my face. If you can't find an answer, try it this way which is supported out of the box.